# Метод определения неравномерности распределения значений

Tags: статистика

Какую методику используют для измерения неравномерности распределения точек на отрезке?
Если точнее, то задача такая: есть отрезок множества точек (порядка от сотен тысяч - до нескольких миллионов) равноудаленных друг от друга. На этом отрезке может быть отмечено несколько десятков позиций. Мне нужно найти критерий для оценки неравномерности распределения этих позиций на упомянутом множестве точек с целью сравнения одного варианта распределения с другим.
Если есть какой-то общепринятый метод или методы, то буду благодарен за ссылку.

Comment: Данный вопрос не соответствует тематике сайта. К тому же, учебные задания допустимы только, если вы сами пытались их решить и предоставите части решения. Вот сайт, на котором стоит задать данный вопрос: https://math.stackexchange.com/ Также советую ознакомиться с этим https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic чтобы впредь не допускать подобных ошибок.

Comment: Это - не учебная задача. Реальная. И да, я пытаюсь сам решить эту задачу, но за одно прошу помощи со стороны.

Comment: Почитайте, пожалуйста, подробнее правила сайта по второй ссылке из моего предыдущего комментария.

Comment: @V-Mor Ну, может это часть разработки какой-то системы

Comment: @V-Mor Не понимаю, почему "вне тематики сайта"??? Тег "статистика", чем не угодил? Можно еще "статистический анализ" добавить. Или "Scipy" - для гурманов. И учебных задач с миллионами точек - ну мне, как минимум не встречалось. И что тогда, свести этот форум окончательно к вопросу "как запрограммировать замену символа А на символ Б в строке за 2 секунды"? Как по мне вопрос - вполне реальная, инженерная, довольно часто встречаемая задача. (И уж точно не для Mathematics).

Comment: @passant, но также точно и не для SO на русском. Здесь нет контекста программирования, администрирования или чего-то подобного. Чистая математика. А в SE вроде даже был специальный сайт для статистики.

Comment: @V-Mor Задача, поставленная ТС не может быть решена иначе, чем с использованием компьютеров,программ и-естественно-методов. т.е."с использованием контекста  ИТ".Если убирать такие вопросы, то следует убрать вопросы, связанные с графами, криптографией, нейросетями, машинным обучением, комбинаторикой, документированием, фотошопом, анализом данных, искусственном интеллекте и много чего еще.Даешь форум вопросов нерадивых студентов, которым лень читать документацию и школьников, бредящих об олимпиадах по программированию.Я за то,что любой вопрос, имеющий отношение к ИТ имеет права быть задан тут.

Answer (score 3):

Если вы считаете, что ваши данные должны быть равномерно распределены на некотором отрезке, то это значит, что в идеале они подчинены равномерному закону распределения.
Реальные данные от этого распределения отличаются. Формально задача формулируется следующим образом: можно ли считать, что распределение выборки (реальных данных) статистически значимо отличается от распределения генеральной совокупности (теоретически).

Есть специальные методы для ответа на этот вопрос, которые используют т.н. критерии проверки согласия.  Их много - от хи-квадрат, Колмогорова-Смирнова (это критерии универсальные, работают для любого распределения) до критериев Шермана, Янга, Неймана-Бартона и пр, заточенных именно на равномерное распределение.

Теория описывается в учебниках по статистике, а как хороший справочник рекомендую - Кобзарь А.И. "Прикладная математическая статистика. Для Инженеров и научных работников" (легко находится в сети).

В Python, библиотеке scipy.stats общие методы реализованы в разных вариантах. Если захотите что-то специальное, то запрограммировать тот-же критерий Шермана самому - большого труда не составляет.

Будут вопросы - задавайте.

Comment: Спасибо за отклик. У меня проблема в том, чтоб сравнить несколько фактических распределений между собой и выяснить какое из них более (менее) равномерно разнесено по области определения.
Я в первом приближении применил среднее расстояние между точками, но сильно сомневаюсь, что не ошибся.
В моей проблеме, кмк, существенно то, что ни о каком стат/распределении тут речи нет - точек слишком мало по сравнению с доменом. Мне нужен только оценочный критерий.

Comment: Еще раз спасибо. Погуглил критерий Шермана - нашел материалы - буду изучать.